# python3: How to iterate over a dictionary of lists

Tags: python-3.x

Given a dictionary of lists, such as:

```
response = {'result': 'success', 'tickers': [{'tag': 'perpetual', 'pair': 'XBT:USD', 'symbol': 'pi_xbtusd', 'markPrice': 42117.8, 'bid': 42109, 'bidSize': 1972, 'ask': 42135.5, 'askSize': 10300, 'vol24h': 139109234, 'openInterest': 109977720.0, 'open24h': 42044, 'indexPrice': 42129.38, 'last': 42111, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T20:01:48.352Z', 'lastSize': 5110, 'suspended': False, 'fundingRate': -6.5375815e-11, 'fundingRatePrediction': -1.813491108e-09}, {'tag': 'perpetual', 'pair': 'ETH:USD', 'symbol': 'pi_ethusd', 'markPrice': 2876.18, 'bid': 2875.4, 'bidSize': 13840, 'ask': 2877.5, 'askSize': 14, 'vol24h': 23454178, 'openInterest': 67282054.0, 'open24h': 2855.7, 'indexPrice': 2875.48, 'last': 2876, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T20:01:40.952Z', 'lastSize': 36, 'suspended': False, 'fundingRate': -2.377857361e-09, 'fundingRatePrediction': -1.4417476403e-08}, {'tag': 'perpetual', 'pair': 'LTC:USD', 'symbol': 'pi_ltcusd', 'markPrice': 122.22, 'bid': 122.19, 'bidSize': 6000, 'ask': 122.32, 'askSize': 7178, 'vol24h': 5077851, 'openInterest': 2401551.0, 'open24h': 124.46, 'indexPrice': 122.25, 'last': 122.24, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T19:53:19.329Z', 'lastSize': 393, 'suspended': False, 'fundingRate': -1.05980559415e-07, 'fundingRatePrediction': -3.76378323108e-07}, {'tag': 'perpetual', 'pair': 'BCH:USD', 'symbol': 'pi_bchusd', 'markPrice': 328.8, 
'bid': 328.5, 'bidSize': 14399, 'ask': 329.1, 'askSize': 4996, 'vol24h': 783335, 'openInterest': 1169452.0, 'open24h': 328.6, 'indexPrice': 328.79, 'last': 329.2, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T19:59:37.624Z', 'lastSize': 1000, 'suspended': False, 'fundingRate': -1.15553001008e-07, 'fundingRatePrediction': -5.7766182238e-08}, {'tag': 'perpetual', 'pair': 'XRP:USD', 'symbol': 'pi_xrpusd', 'markPrice': 0.7866, 'bid': 0.7864, 'bidSize': 2484, 'ask': 0.7875, 'askSize': 5539, 'vol24h': 4416861, 
'openInterest': 2347174.0, 'open24h': 0.7995, 'indexPrice': 0.78703, 'last': 0.7878, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T19:58:00.039Z', 'lastSize': 500, 'suspended': False, 'fundingRate': -3.5410563455435e-05, 'fundingRatePrediction': -0.000144914791833213}, {'tag': 'quarter', 'pair': 'XBT:USD', 'symbol': 'fi_xbtusd_220325', 'markPrice': 42124, 'bid': 42107, 'bidSize': 657, 
'ask': 42147, 'askSize': 337, 'vol24h': 4516774, 'openInterest': 10453918.0, 'open24h': 42165, 'indexPrice': 42129.38, 'last': 42115, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T19:58:21.871Z', 'lastSize': 1, 'suspended': False}, {'tag': 'quarter', 'pair': 'ETH:USD', 'symbol': 'fi_ethusd_220325', 'markPrice': 2878.92, 'bid': 2877.95, 'bidSize': 1409, 'ask': 2881.6, 'askSize': 1409, 'vol24h': 1296736, 'openInterest': 10246247.0, 'open24h': 2858.55, 'indexPrice': 2875.48, 'last': 2879, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T20:00:41.221Z', 'lastSize': 15, 'suspended': False}, {'tag': 'semiannual', 'pair': 'XBT:USD', 'symbol': 'fi_xbtusd_220624', 'markPrice': 42631.8, 'bid': 42600.5, 'bidSize': 19528, 'ask': 42663.5, 'askSize': 1736, 'vol24h': 1254458, 'openInterest': 11690183.0, 'open24h': 42774, 'indexPrice': 42129.38, 'last': 42625.5, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T19:53:17.145Z', 'lastSize': 432, 'suspended': False}, {'tag': 'semiannual', 'pair': 'ETH:USD', 'symbol': 'fi_ethusd_220624', 'markPrice': 2911.98, 'bid': 2909.6, 'bidSize': 500, 'ask': 2914.4, 'askSize': 1336, 'vol24h': 472237, 'openInterest': 2858983.0, 'open24h': 2907.35, 'indexPrice': 2875.48, 'last': 2911.5, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T20:00:41.283Z', 'lastSize': 3, 'suspended': False}, {'tag': 'quarter', 'pair': 'BCH:USD', 'symbol': 'fi_bchusd_220325', 'markPrice': 325.3, 'bid': 324.8, 'bidSize': 8088, 'ask': 325.7, 'askSize': 500, 'vol24h': 2, 'openInterest': 643021.0, 'open24h': 329.7, 'indexPrice': 328.79, 'last': 329.2, 'lastTime': '2022-02-13T22:10:43.587Z', 'lastSize': 1, 'suspended': False}, {'tag': 'quarter', 'pair': 'XRP:USD', 'symbol': 'fi_xrpusd_220325', 'markPrice': 0.786, 'bid': 0.7856, 'bidSize': 689, 'ask': 0.7869, 'askSize': 689, 'vol24h': 118806, 'openInterest': 1025239.0, 'open24h': 0.8029, 'indexPrice': 0.78703, 'last': 0.7873, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T19:56:30.286Z', 'lastSize': 1, 'suspended': False}, {'tag': 'quarter', 'pair': 'LTC:USD', 'symbol': 'fi_ltcusd_220325', 'markPrice': 121.95, 'bid': 121.86, 'bidSize': 689, 'ask': 122.05, 'askSize': 689, 'vol24h': 348007, 'openInterest': 1374020.0, 'open24h': 124.13, 'indexPrice': 122.25, 'last': 121.87, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T19:41:27.298Z', 'lastSize': 1, 'suspended': False}, {'tag': 'month', 'pair': 'ETH:USD', 'symbol': 'fi_ethusd_220225', 'markPrice': 2872.75, 'bid': 2872.05, 'bidSize': 
27795, 'ask': 2874.4, 'askSize': 1431, 'vol24h': 535685, 'openInterest': 367366.0, 'open24h': 2850.15, 'indexPrice': 2875.48, 'last': 2879.7, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T19:50:17.018Z', 'lastSize': 1022, 'suspended': False}, {'tag': 'month', 'pair': 'XBT:USD', 'symbol': 'fi_xbtusd_220225', 'markPrice': 42121.8, 'bid': 42088.5, 'bidSize': 1831, 'ask': 42164.5, 'askSize': 1831, 'vol24h': 1113877, 'openInterest': 2636541.0, 'open24h': 42051.5, 'indexPrice': 42129.38, 'last': 42136.5, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T19:37:56.616Z', 'lastSize': 1831, 'suspended': False}, {'tag': 'month', 'pair': 'XRP:USD', 'symbol': 'fi_xrpusd_220225', 'markPrice': 0.7842, 'bid': 0.7839, 'bidSize': 1211, 'ask': 0.785, 'askSize': 711, 'vol24h': 175205, 'openInterest': 86563.0, 'open24h': 0.7954, 'indexPrice': 0.78703, 'last': 0.786, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T19:58:23.106Z', 'lastSize': 149, 'suspended': False}, {'tag': 'month', 'pair': 'BCH:USD', 'symbol': 'fi_bchusd_220225', 'markPrice': 327.6, 'bid': 327.2, 'bidSize': 8174, 'ask': 328.1, 'askSize': 7185, 'vol24h': 0, 'openInterest': 62616.0, 'indexPrice': 328.79, 'last': 317.6, 'lastTime': '2022-02-12T22:07:56.388Z', 'lastSize': 100, 'suspended': False}, {'tag': 'month', 'pair': 'LTC:USD', 'symbol': 'fi_ltcusd_220225', 'markPrice': 121.88, 'bid': 121.76, 'bidSize': 1211, 'ask': 121.98, 'askSize': 711, 'vol24h': 72414, 'openInterest': 118755.0, 'open24h': 125.27, 'indexPrice': 122.25, 'last': 121.49, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T19:22:21.289Z', 'lastSize': 711, 'suspended': False}, {'symbol': 'in_xbtusd', 'last': 42129, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T20:02:00.000Z'}, {'symbol': 'in_xrpusd', 'last': 0.787, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T20:02:00.000Z'}, {'symbol': 'in_ethusd', 'last': 2875.48, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T20:02:00.000Z'}, {'symbol': 'in_ltcusd', 'last': 122.25, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T20:02:00.000Z'}, {'symbol': 'in_bchusd', 'last': 328.79, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T20:02:00.000Z'}, {'symbol': 'rr_xbtusd', 'last': 42528, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T16:00:00.000Z'}, {'symbol': 'rr_xrpusd', 'last': 0.802, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T16:00:00.000Z'}, {'symbol': 'rr_ethusd', 'last': 2934.51, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T16:00:00.000Z'}, {'symbol': 'rr_ltcusd', 'last': 125.71, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T16:00:00.000Z'}, {'symbol': 'rr_bchusd', 'last': 327.49, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T16:00:00.000Z'}], 'serverTime': '2022-02-14T20:02:01.523Z'}
```

With this for loop, I can get all response tags. Is there a way to get a specific one?

```
for key, value_list in response.items():
    print(f'the {key} are:')
    for item in value_list:
        print(item)
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Jason That's not json, it's just a regular dict.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Include the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
for obj in response['result']:      # to take result

    print(obj)

for obj in response['tickers']:     # to take tickers

    print(obj)

for obj in response['serverTime']:  # to take serverTime

    print(obj)

##################################### to reach elements with 'tag' key

listTags=[]

for obj in response['tickers']:

    if('tag' in obj.keys()):

        listTags.append(obj['tag'])

#####################################
```

Comment: Thaknks Hasan...With this aproach I can get: {'tag': 'perpetual', 'pair': 'XRP:USD', 'symbol': 'pi_xrpusd', 'markPrice': 0.7866, 'bid': 0.7864, 'bidSize': 2484, 'ask': 0.7875, 'askSize': 5539, 'vol24h': 4416861, 'openInterest': 2347174.0, 'open24h': 0.7995, 'indexPrice': 0.78703, 'last': 
0.7878, 'lastTime': '2022-02-14T19:58:00.039Z', 'lastSize': 500, 'suspended': False, 'fundingRate': -3.5410563455435e-05, 
'fundingRatePrediction': -0.000144914791833213}
And so on, Can I access to 'tag' elements, one by one?

Comment: Please check my updated answer!

Comment: Thanks Hasan! Get all keys inside tag, bus I can't get the values for each one. tag parpetual, tag pair, tag symbol, tag markPrice and so on.